# PHP Update in While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, pdo, while-loop

I've searched far and wide on how to accomplish something like this without result.

What I want is to update a single row to 1 when the button is pressed, instead it updates every row.

Php:

```
if(isset($_GET['updateValidation'])) {
$stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare("UPDATE comment_imgs SET validation=1 WHERE id=".$id."");
$stmt5->execute();
}
```

Form:

```
<form method="get">
<input type="submit" name="updateValidation" id="updateValidation">
<label for="updateValidation" class="btn btn-primary">Update Validation</label>
</form>
```

.. and how I have $id defined:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$id = $row['id'];
```

**EDIT:** Excuse my mess of a code.

```
    <body>
        <div class="container">         
            <div class="page-header">
                <h1>View Uploaded Projects <small>Admin backend</small> </h1>
            </div>
            <?php include("dbconfig.php");?>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="formlayout">
                    <h1><small>Sort by:</small></h1>
                    <form method="get" class="form-inline">
                    <input id="sortDate" name="sortDate" type="submit">
                    <label for="sortDate" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="sortDateCSS">Date</label><br>
                    <input id="sortProject" name="sortProject" type="submit">
                    <label for="sortProject" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="sortProjectCSS">Project</label><br>
                    <input id="sortUser" name="sortUser" type="submit">
                    <label for="sortUser" class="btn btn-outline-info" id="sortUserCSS">User</label><br>
                    </form>
                    </div>
<?php 

/*include("class.user.php");*/
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];

/* Laddar sidan med nyaste datum först */
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs ORDER BY date DESC");
$stmt->execute();

/* Sortera projekt */
if(isset($_GET['sortDate'])){
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs ORDER BY date DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
}

if(isset($_GET['sortProject'])){
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs ORDER BY project_id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
}

if(isset($_GET['sortUser'])){
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM comment_imgs ORDER BY user_id DESC");
    $stmt->execute();
}
/* Sortering slut */


/* Loop för Card Display / Modals */
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
$id = $row['id'];
$date = $row['date'];
$comment = $row['comment']; 
$project_id = $row['project_id'];
$user_name = $row['user_name'];
$validation = $row['validation'];
?>

<!-- Card Display -->                   
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" id="display">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $project_id;?></h5>
<p class="card-text"><?php echo $date;?></p>
<p class="card-text"><?php echo $user_name;?></p>
<p class="card-text"><?php echo $comment;?></p>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>" id="formButtons">
 Button
</button>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModal<?php echo $id;?>Label"><?php echo $project_id;?></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php echo $date;?>
            <?php echo $comment;?>
            <?php echo $user_name;?>
                <form method="get">
            <input type="submit" name="updateValidation" id="updateValidation">
            <label for="updateValidation" class="btn btn-primary">Update Validation</label>
            </form>
            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['updateValidation'])) {
                $stmt5 = $DB_con->prepare("UPDATE comment_imgs SET validation=1 WHERE id=".$id."");
                $stmt5->execute();
                }
            ?>
            <?php if ($validation == 1) {
                echo "Avklarad";
                } else {
                    echo "WIP";
                }?>
            <?php

            $stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT image_path, image_name, display_id FROM uploads LEFT JOIN comment_imgs ON uploads.display_id = comment_imgs.project_id");
            $stmt2->execute();

            while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
            $image_path = $row2["image_path"]."/".$row2["image_name"];
            $display_id = $row2['display_id'];

            ?><?php if ($project_id == $display_id){?>
            <a href="<?php echo $image_path; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" class="images" /></a><?php }} ?>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
    }
?>
</div>

        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    </body>
```

Comment: You need to rework your logic. It seems like it is working as intended...

Comment: Even if I put the code outside of the loop it still updates every row instead of one.

Comment: You need to put the ID into the form, and then use `$_GET['id']` in the `UPDATE`.

Comment: You should also use parametrized queries instead of concatenating variables, to protect against SQL injection.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using PDO you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with placeholder values and supply any user data as separate arguments. In this code you have potentially severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Never use string interpolation or concatenation and instead use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and never put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query. Refer to [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) for general guidance and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to run a while loop to update every record with a unique ID. in MySQL, the [Update](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) statement updates all rows that meet the where clause. Putting it in a while loop is redundant and inefficient. You only need to run update once to update all rows with your `id` field.

You should also understand that if the string is outside the while loop, it will set the string to what the value of `$id` is at that time, and use it inside the loop. Maybe update your question with code that isnt broken up